# My unsigned short pointers are returning unexpected results. Why?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, math

I'm writing in C for OSX, running on a 64-bit machine in 32-bit mode. I'm compiling using GCC for 386. The project is large; I've not seen any odd behavior from the compiler (possibly until now.) The application is multithreaded, and this code is meant to be, but is being run single-threaded at this time. I am compiling using the position independent clib, and using posix threads, when threading. This code, btw, acts exactly the same if I *do* thread it.

The following is a simplified procedure that demonstrates the problem in the simplest form. Basically, I'm moving 16-bit image channels here from one set of three RGB channels (mr,mg,mb) to another set of 3 RGB channels (lr,lg,lb) of exactly the same size. The fragment, as I'm about to dump it, works perfectly:

```
void lrip_me(   unsigned short *mr, // RIP from source image
                unsigned short *mg,
                unsigned short *mb,
                unsigned short *lr, // into RGB layer
                unsigned short *lg,
                unsigned short *lb,
                struct layer *lay,
                long start,long finish)
{
long xw,yw;
long xf,yf;
long x,y;
unsigned long offset;

    xw = lay->parent->x;
    yw = lay->parent->y;
    xf = xw - 1;
    yf = yw - 1;

    for (y=start; y<finish; y++)
    {
        for (x=0; x<xw; x++)
        {
            offset = (y * xw) + x;
            if (x==0 || x==xf || y==0 || y==yf) // then on edge
            {
                lr[offset] = mr[offset];
                lg[offset] = mg[offset];
                lb[offset] = mb[offset];
            }
            else
            {
                lr[offset] = mr[offset];
                lg[offset] = mg[offset];
                lb[offset] = mb[offset];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the action at the edge of the image and inside the edges is the same; I'm simply moving the data. And this works -- the output of this is an image in the lr,lg, and lb channels.

BUT. If, inside the else clause, I change the lines to read...

```
            lr[offset] = mr[offset-xw];
            lg[offset] = mg[offset-xw];
            lb[offset] = mb[offset-xw];
```

...you'd expect the interior of the image to move one scan line, as the data fetches would be coming from a full scan line's distance away but going to an un-shifted target location. Instead, the output looks completely random. Like the shorts were loaded on the wrong boundaries, perhaps, or from somewhere else. This does the same thing...

```
            lr[offset] = mr[offset-1];
            lg[offset] = mg[offset-1];
            lb[offset] = mb[offset-1];
```

...there, I'd expect the image to move one pixel horizontally. No. Same result -- purest hash.

I have tried changing to pointer math instead of arrays //*(mr+offset-1)// and get exactly the same result. I've compiled it in a library, and inside objc environment. I've tried using even offset, thinking perhaps the compiler is confused about the size of the data. I get the same results every time. The offset value can be used as is, but ONLY as is. It can't be modified inside the brackets, and furthermore, it can't be modified OUTSIDE the brackets, just being treated as a long.

I have NO idea what is going on here. I would surely appreciate it if someone would help me understand what is.

A little background; this is a RIP (remove isolated pixel) operation, or at least, it will be, if I can get at the 8 pixels surrounding the one the loop is currently looking at. That's why the edges are treated differently; I don't want to run the 8-pixel lookaround on the edges, only inside them where I'll always have all 8 to look at:

```
ooo
oxo
ooo
```

In this test case, I've removed all the RIP code, as it adds a lot of complexity and doesn't shed any light on the problem. It's simply (hah!) a situtation where array and pointer offsets don't seem to work sensibly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index function assumes the 2D arrays are in [row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order).

```
offset = (y * xw) + x;
```

Perhaps they are in column-major order.

Comment: The layout of arrays in memory is completely specified by the C language. There is no room for implementations to vary.

Comment: No, I'm the one who put them in row major order. And as I said, the example works as given -- the output is perfect given that calculation; it wouldn't if the offset calculation was wrong. Agreed?

Comment: @fyngyrz, not agreed. In the simple case of copying (or anything where you only operate on a single pixel (array element)), it doesn't matter what order you iterate through them as long as you still generate every offset.  However, on thinking more about it, I think if row-major vs column-major order were your problem, then your second modification (`foo[offset - 1]`) should have worked.

Comment: @rlibby, this isn't such a simple case, because it leaves the edges untouched and in place. If the row - column ordering were different, the pixels on the edge would not BE on the edge. The image, btw, is not square. When the offset has been modified, the jumbled results do not include the edge.

Comment: What is going on here is something with the actual math of either **(a)** the inside of the array offset, ie inside the square brackets, or **(b)** in the pointer offset math, which produces the same unexpected results. What is really throwing me is that I use similar approaches elsewhere - in creating blur, for example, which also requires sampling around the pixel of interest - and have experienced no problems.

Comment: @R.., not true. To the C language, fyngyrz has 1-dimensional arrays. The two-dimensionality added on top of these 1-dimensional arrays is a consequence of the offset function.

Comment: @fyngyrz, one potential issue is your mixing of signed and unsigned longs.  (This causes conversion of the signed long to unsigned long.)  However, in this case, `xw` is positive so it shouldn't cause a problem.  If you were trying to *add* a *negative* value, you would have a problem.

Comment: I've tried using both signed and unsigned long as the offset type. Same results either way. Also, (offset-1) is still a positive number, as is (offset-xw), considering that it only happens on y lines 1 and forward, where it is at a minimum, xw unsigned shorts into the array. I'm feeling more than a little desperate at this point. I'm going to reboot. :(

Comment: good grief. Solved. Wasn't anything to do with this (unsurprisingly) and not a compiler problem at all. Sorry to have wasted your time, folks. Sigh.